# How would a FX price probability distibution function look?

Tags: fx, distribution, price

I would like to see how the currency price levels are distributed in a probability function. But I don't even know if there is such a thing or if perhaps its just common knowledge and readily available.

Possibly related questions:

- [How do you synthesize a probability density function (pdf) from equally weighted price data?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/how-do-you-synthesize-a-probability-density-function-pdf-from-equally-weighted)

---

Q: **How can I plot the price probability function for a currency pair, for a certain period, $x$?**

(Are there any readily available tools for doing this?)

---

UPDATE:

As a clarification to some of the comments, I would like to be more specific, and mention that I have nearly 4 months of EUR/USD M1 OHLCV data (5x ~112K points) that I would like to turn into a PDF. The answers provided so far has not gotten me any closer to this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the risk neutral density implied by option prices and have a look at that. The implied probabilities are given by the prices of butterfly spreads in the market. This is common knowledge. Page 241 of this book explains how you could go about doing it in Excel: https://gaussiandotblog.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/wiley-trading-giles-peter-jewitt-fx-derivatives-trader-school-2015-wiley.pdf

Comment: Thanks, nice book. I ran some of its examples, but i must admit it did not really get me to where I wanted to be. Mind that I am not a *quant*. I was thinking along the line of KDE, but I don't know how to apply it, or if it is even correct to do so.

Comment: The section that I cite tells you exactly step by step how to use option prices to see " see how the currency price levels are distributed in a probability function" as you asked. So I am not really sure what there is left to be answered?

Comment: Trying to follow your suggestion, there are no instructions, nor code examples in the section you mention (Chapter 13). Its just a bunch of graphs. Moving on to Chapter "G", there are some talking about pricing. However, looking at the accompanying Excel sheet named: `Practical G - Generating a Probability Density Function.xlsm`. Looking at the tab named "Task A3", there seem to be nothing to help me do what you suggest. I have nearly 4 Months of M1 OHLC data (4x ~112K points) that I would like to turn into a PDF. I don't see how or where I can paste any OHLC data in any of those columns.

Comment: If you have 4 months of FX price data just calculate the returns and then generate a histogram using them. You will get an empirical pdf of the historical price changes. That is straight forward to do. What the book, me, and the other answer in the thread suggest to do is to use OPTION prices to extract the IMPLIED risk neutral forward looking distribution. the chapter I reference gives examples of what these distributions could look like. The following practical gives you exact step by step instructions and code to extract the implied pdf from option prices.

Comment: So just to be absolutely clear: using your price data you could ignore our recommendations and simply calculate daily log returns as log(P(t-1)/P(t)) where P(t) is the price on the t day. Then just make a histogram of these returns.

Comment: The reason you are being told to use option prices to extract the implied density instead is that the resulting pdf is often forward looking and contains more information than the historical pdf. For example, if you look at some of the examples the author gives in chapter 13, you will see there are pdfs that give a small probability of a very large drop below a pegged/managed level. Another example is that you could have a bimodal pdf. These usually result when there is an anticipated event that could cause the price to jump. You will miss these possibilities simply looking at the historical.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to clarify! Those last comments made the difference. I will try to follow both methods, and see where it get me. However, I also realized that this SE forum is probably not for me, and I will definitely give it a 2nd and 3rd though before posting here again. The *quant* and *options* language here, is way too full of tech jargon, and you need to spend a week just trying to understand the language in most answers.

Comment: Yes, I think we assumed from the get go that you understood options theory. I can see how the answers would not make sense in the case that you do not. Just to give you an intuitive explanation: basically there is some math that says that the future distribution of prices and the current option price are linked. So via a backwards process you can take the option prices and see what they say about what people think the future distribution of the FX rate will be. Same way that if you are offered 2:1 odds on a bet that implies that the event has a 1/3 chance of happening.

Answer (score 4):

Assume we knew the density function $f$ of the FX price that we observe in the market. Then the market price of a call option $C(K)$ with strike $K$ would be
\begin{align*} 
C(K)&=e^{-rT} \int_0^{\infty}(s-K)^+ f(s)ds \\
&=e^{-rT} \left( \int_K^{\infty} s f(s)ds - K \int_K^{\infty}f(s)ds \right) \tag*{(1)}. 
\end{align*}

$C(K)$ is a market price and we want to recover $f$ from Eq(1). So we just have to differentiate twice with respect to K. We differentiate once to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dK}C(K)e^{rT} &= -K f(K) - \left( \int_K^{\infty}  f(s)ds - K f(K) \right) \\
&= -  \int_K^{\infty}  f(s)ds
\end{align*}
Differentiating again 
$$\frac{d^2}{dK^2}C(K)e^{rT} = f(K). \tag*{(2)}$$
This shows that the "real" density can be obtained from the call prices. As an easy approximation to Eq(2), we can use the following
$$f(K) \cong \left[ \frac{ C(K+h)+C(K-h)-2C(K)}{h^2} \right]e^{rT}. \tag*{(3)}$$
How do we use this formula? We can collect a set of market prices of calls, for all the strikes corresponding to some maturity, and interpolate the volatilities. Suppose we have 6 market prices. Then we get the implied volatilities  from the options prices and interpolate the vols to have a " more dense" set of vols. For example if we originally have market implied vols 85%, 90%, 95%, 100% 105% 110%, we interpolate to obtain 70%, 71%, 72%, ... , 140%. Then we use Black-Scholes formula to obtain $C(K)$ and plug it into Eq(3) in order to get the desired implied density $f$. This can be done in Excel quite easily.

Of course there are many ways to interpolate volatilities and also to extrapolate them in both ends.

Comment: You already mention it, but for further highlight: **strive to interpolate implied vols, rather than option prices**, as you get a more robust density estimate that way (your density will be much more sensitive to interpolation in price space than implied vol space). If you have option prices, turn them into implied vols by inverting the BS formula.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I am neither a *quant*, nor well versed in the options language, I don't see clearly how to apply that formula for common *forex* price action. For example, what would I use for the various quantities/variables shown? Also how do you measure *volume* in terms of % (of what)? Do you have any references or links to where I can find some examples, applied to fx market?

Comment: Do you know how to price a call option in a spreadsheet and how to use the Excel solver?

Comment: Nope. I generally don't use Excel, especially not to solve or plot anything. I first try to do this manually. If numerical integration is needed I'll generally use Matlab, R or custom python.

Comment: I said Excel because is the simplest program. Obviously,  you can use whatever programming language you want. If you can price call options with Matlab or Python and know how to use a solver, then you can get the implied density very easily.

Comment: Ok, easy or not, but my point is that I was asking specifically about *forex*, while you give an answer about pricing *options*, which to me, seem totally irrelevant. Either way, i have no idea how to apply your pricing solution using the basic variables available from forex.

Comment: It isn't irrelevant. The option prices will imply the density of the underlying forex. If you look at equation two it gives you the probability density function of the underlying in term of the discounted second derivative of the call option price. So you get the underlying forex density by looking at this. Quotes for butterflies in the market are used to get a discrete approximation.

Comment: @not2qubit: : I don't understand your comment. I was just trying to help you to show you how to use the formula to obtain your implied density function, which is something that can be done in Matlab in 5 minutes. Also, it doesn't matter whether your option is on a stock or on a Fx Rate, the procedure is the same. But to be honest, I couldn't care less.

Comment: @non2qubit It is not irrelevant because the option prices are from options on the underlying FX you are concerned with...

Comment: @ubm Thanks for your patience and sorry for not understanding the language you use. I've upvoted your answer, but chose to accept the one of roz because of more clear explanation.